# curl --cert using the wrong certificate

Tags: java, rest, ssl, curl

I'm trying to sent a HTTP request to GET some response from another server in my company.  I'm sending a http request using curl, specifying the cert and key which is associated to our application.  When sending the request I get an error from the server I'm hitting telling me my certificate serial number is not associated to our application. The certificate serial number it references is NOT the one I'm specifying in my curl request.  It is the serial number of another certificate which I'm actually able to see in my browsers settings, so it's clearly picking up an already existing certificate.. and not the one I'm specifying in my curl command

I've tried putting a typo in my cert name and key name, to see if I would get a different result.. however it gives the exact same error with the same certificate serial number, so it seems the request is completely ignoring my key and cert specified in the command

curl command below:  cert, key, url name are masked but this is the exact format i'm using.  including file extensions.

curl --cert *CERTNAME*.cer --key *KEYNAME*.pem "*DESTINATIONURL*"

I'm expecting a JSON response from the server.  However, I am getting the following error message:
{"ErrorCode":"*****","ErrorMsg":"Authentication error for App ID []. Reason: Failed to verify application authentication data: CertificateSN \"630************************\" is unauthorized"}

Comment: " including file extensions." they do not matter for certificates/key stuff. Did you look in the manual about the `--cert` option and its restriction on the **content** of the files? Did you try with `--verbose` or even `--trace` to get more information on what is happening?